In Visual Studio Code, how can I rename a variable in Python and also update its occurrences in ReST formatted documentation?
Suppose I have:
class Hello:
  """An example class."""
  world: str
  """This is the only field on :py:class:`Hello`."""

It is documented using the ReST format, meant to be used with Sphinx.
In VS Code, if I refactor Hello to something else, the reference py:class:`Hello will not be updated. Is there anything I can do (either in the settings, or using an extension) so that this update will be performed?

As far as I know, Pylance's support for rST docstrings isn't very good. Not sure about Jedi though; Jedi does support renaming, and it "can infer function arguments", but nothing is said about whether its renaming capabilities also extend to Sphinx docstrings or not.

Unfortunately, there is no built-in functionality in VS Code or python extension that automatically updates Sphinx references when you refactor class names.
The most reliable method is to use the "Search and Replace" feature to manually update the references after refactoring.
